# Why a zk-rollup should provide data availability given it can use zkp to prove correctness?

Tags: rollups, data, availability

The whole idea behind zkp is to prove correctness of the result of a computation without actually disclosing the inputs that you might want to keep secret. So why in the context of zk-rollups it is so important that all the calldata is stored somewhere (on-chain or off-chain)?

Answer (score 2):

The validity proof shows the state transition is valid, but you still need access to the state to do most kinds of transactions.  Imagine if a powerful entity hid all the valid transactions from you and only submitted proofs of correct state transitions.  You wouldn't even know what your own balance is.